# Reading Entries from ASCII file into JAVA(The first entry is what determines record length as well as total number of records)

Tags: java, ascii

Making use of an ASCII .DAT file that contains multiple records of a fixed length I would like to read each record and generate an output based on its certain portions of its contents.

So far my program does exactly this but I was alerted to the fact that the first field in each .DAT file starts with the record length and number of records, the only issue I am having is reading this first field and extracting the data as usable, the issue is that the data is in ASCII chars and not decimal numbers.

Below is a code snipet in BASIC that reads the same file and extracts the initial data required

```
    CLS
    INPUT "Survey System Data File? : ", survey$
    survey$ = "f:\apps\survey\" + survey$
    reclen = 3004
    OPEN survey$ + ".dat" FOR RANDOM AS 1 LEN = reclen
    FIELD #1, 3 AS RL$, 9 AS n$
    GET #1, 1
    RL = CVI(RL$): n = CVI(n$)
    PRINT "Record Length     = "; RL
    reclen = RL
    PRINT "Number of Records = "; n
    CLOSE #1
```

Is there a way of doing something similar in Java?

The initial record and second record are seen below. The second record starts from 0001511

#Å            Õ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            000151115 2                      351228 6 8131720                                                    1121211  12111121121111111112112111                 Treat people fairly. Motivated people who go the extra mile should be recognised. Trust employees to make decisions and find out what is best for the business. Examine the workload and the performance and timing of the work.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        11 6 5 6 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                2003/10/007:12 21    111                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2 1154 1 1 113 1   1   1   1   1                                                                          4000100  0  0  0   400     0     0     0   400     4100.0000.0000.0     0    0   10   24                                                                        12111none                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 9    1346

As you can see the initial characters are ASCII chars and not decimals that I'm looking for.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can certainly read bytes from the file and get the numeric values from them, but it is not clear how many bytes are in each number or what their endianness is. I'm not familiar with the dialect of BASIC above. Can you explain what it's doing? `ObjectInputStream.readShort()` and perhaps `Short.reverseBytes()` may be helpful here.

Comment: Hi David, as far as I understand it the first 5 lines of code are to open a file specified, the magic happens in the 6th and 8th line . FIELD #1, 3 AS RL$, 9 AS n$, here it references the very first field in the file as being 3 chars which it sets to the variable RL (Record Length), it then references the next variable as being the following 9 chars which it sets to n (total number of records). Line 8 is the conversion from ascii to integer . These two inputs are what I'm after. specifically how they are converted from ascii text chars to usable decimal numbers.

Comment: Here is a description of the CVI function in basic. "The CVI function converts a 2-byte string that holds an integer to an actual
integer value."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way around this issue as the initial record of the file is basically a blank indicator record and so using this initial record length I was able to find the recurring record length of the others.